# Getting error in jsp as - Syntax error on token ",", delete this token

Tags: jsp

I am getting an error

> Syntax error on token ",", delete this token

in line number 4 after params.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.security.*" %>
<%!
 public boolean verifyChecksum(params, checksumReceived_from_Payu)
 {
        String hashSequence = "udf10|udf9|udf8|udf7|udf6|udf5|udf4|udf3|udf2|udf1|email|firstname|productinfo|amount|txnid";
        String[] hashVarSeq=hashSequence.split("\\|");
        String hashString="";
        String hash="";
        String merchant_key="";
        String salt="";

        hashString=hashString.concat(salt);
        hashString=hashString.concat("|");
        hashString=hashString.concat(params.get(status));
        hashString=hashString.concat("|");

        for(String part : hashVarSeq)
        {
            hashString= (empty(params.get(part)))?hashString.concat(""):hashString.concat(params.get(part));
            hashString=hashString.concat("|");
        }
        hashString=hashString.concat(merchant_key);

        hash=hashCal("SHA-512",hashString);

        if(hash.equals(checksumReceived_from_Payu))
                return true;
        else
                return false;       
}            
    }        
%>
```

I have updated my code. But still, error remains. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should add type to arguments, for example, `(HashMap params, boolean checksumReceived_from_Payu)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I tried your solution but still facing the same issue. I have updated my question above with the latest code.

Comment: Just stop putting Java code in JSPs. Put Java code in Java classes, where it belongs. You haven't added any type on the arguments of the method.

Comment: The variable `status` should be defined.